# DS-5 configuration for Cortex-M7

Tags: c, debugging, compilation, arm, cortex-m

I'm starting my very first project with arm device. Concretely, I'd like to do some image processing on the cortex-M7 programming in C/C++. I got the DS-5 community working just fine and I'm following the basic Hello World tutorial in here: https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/ds-5-development-studio/resources/tutorials/getting-started-with-ds-5-ce-and-armv8-foundation-platform

I'm struggling to accomplish the following:

1. Get the right toolchain: I got arm-eabi 2.24 from here(http://gnutoolchains.com/download/). Is this what I'm supposed to use? should I use arm-elf instead?
2. In the tutorial, it describes how to create a debug configuration for a cortex-A9 device. However, I have a cortex-M7. I know I can add a new configuration database from Window>Preferences>DS-5>ConfigurationDatabase. Where can I find the database files for the cortex-M7? I believe those files are available somewhere in the arm site but I can't find them.

Sorry if these questions aren't so interesting... I'm new to this and I need these two problems to be solved in order to start doing some actual work.

Comment: You may have trouble with the tutorial you are following as the Cortex-M7 is a ARMv7E-M architecture and not ARMv8.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ARM DS-5 license, you can send email to support@arm.com for support.

Actually, these kind of questions can be answered from articles of Arm public web sites.

Adding a new configuration database to DS-5 
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0446o/deb1359985233115.html

Answer (score 0):

The latest GNU ARM toolchain can be found at https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm